# Multi Region not connected everywhere

Tags: cockroachdb

I would like to be able to use cockroach DB in multiple DC. 20 zones and after that it will increase.

I would like to know if it's possible to have the data everywhere, but i dont want to be connected to every zones. I'm using multiple VPN and i'm limited of the numbers of VPN i can connected to a zone.

I created a multi region cluster. But all my region are connected together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All nodes in a CockroachDB cluster must be able to talk to each other directly. CockroachDB clusters will not function properly without this.

Please see the [production checklist](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v19.1/recommended-production-settings.html#networking) for details on how nodes can be configured in various scenarios.